# throw up the red flag for someone -- meaning?

Tags: meaning

From the movie [The Sacrament](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sacrament_%282013_film%29):

> — I'm trying to keep it together, so I can ask intelligent questions, but jet lag's kicked in and I am starting to melt. Jake, what do you think of all this so far? Give me your professional assessment.
>   — I don't know. I mean, I'm naturally cynical, but... The fact that a bunch of drug addicts and alcoholics actually pulled this thing together is a little bit impressive. The fact that they sold all their worldly possessions to do it... I don't know, just **throws up the red flag** for me a little bit. I feel like, I mean, if this is like a place to come and get clean or do a little bit of thinking for a month, it's perfect. I think it is an actual sustainable lifestyle for, you know, 60-something elderly people.

What does he exactly mean by that expression?

Comment: A red flag is a sign of danger; highway workers in the US, for instance, often put up red flags on the approaches to worksites so approaching cars will slow down. Jake means that the addicts' uncharacteristic behaviour makes him  suspicious. I have usualy encountered this as *raises* a red flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the plot of "The Sacrament", it seems that '***throws up the red flag***' has something to do with skepticism, *in my opinion*.

Jack finds the fact of selling worldly possessions a little skeptical.

Hope this would help.